# CC3000 + Arduino [HELP]

Tags: arduino

```
#include <Adafruit_CC3000.h>
#include <ccspi.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "utility/debug.h"
//#include "utility/socket.h"


// These are the interrupt and control pins
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_IRQ   3  // MUST be an interrupt pin!
// These can be any two pins
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_VBAT  5
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_CS    10
// Use hardware SPI for the remaining pins
// On an UNO, SCK = 13, MISO = 12, and MOSI = 11
Adafruit_CC3000 cc3000 = Adafruit_CC3000(ADAFRUIT_CC3000_CS, ADAFRUIT_CC3000_IRQ, ADAFRUIT_CC3000_VBAT,
                                         SPI_CLOCK_DIV2); // you can change this clock speed but DI



#define WLAN_SSID       "ssid"        // cannot be longer than 32 characters!
#define WLAN_PASS       "pass"

// Security can be WLAN_SEC_UNSEC, WLAN_SEC_WEP, WLAN_SEC_WPA or WLAN_SEC_WPA2
#define WLAN_SECURITY   WLAN_SEC_WPA2

//Web transactions on port 80
Adafruit_CC3000_Server server(80);
Adafruit_CC3000_Client client;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(F("Hello, CC3000!\n")); 

  displayDriverMode();
  Serial.print("Free RAM: "); Serial.println(getFreeRam(), DEC);

  /* Initialise the module */
  Serial.println(F("\nInitialising the CC3000 ..."));
  if (!cc3000.begin())
  {
    Serial.println(F("Unable to initialise the CC3000! Check your wiring?"));
    while(1);
  }

  /* Optional: Update the Mac Address to a known value */

  uint8_t macAddress[6] = { 0x08, 0x00, 0x28, 0x01, 0x79, 0xB7 };
   if (!cc3000.setMacAddress(macAddress))
   {
     Serial.println(F("Failed trying to update the MAC address"));
     while(1);
   }
  /* End Optional */

  uint16_t firmware = checkFirmwareVersion();
  if ((firmware != 0x113) && (firmware != 0x118)) {
    Serial.println(F("Wrong firmware version!"));
    for(;;);
  }

  displayMACAddress();

  /* Delete any old connection data on the module */
  Serial.println(F("\nDeleting old connection profiles"));
  if (!cc3000.deleteProfiles()) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed!"));
    while(1);
  }

  /* Attempt to connect to an access point */
  char *ssid = WLAN_SSID;             /* Max 32 chars */
  Serial.print(F("\nAttempting to connect to ")); Serial.println(ssid);

  /* NOTE: Secure connections are not available in 'Tiny' mode! */
  if (!cc3000.connectToAP(WLAN_SSID, WLAN_PASS, WLAN_SECURITY)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed!"));
    while(1);
  }

  Serial.println(F("Connected!"));

  /* Wait for DHCP to complete */
  Serial.println(F("Request DHCP"));
  while (!cc3000.checkDHCP())
  {
    delay(100); // ToDo: Insert a DHCP timeout!
  }  

  /* Display the IP address DNS, Gateway, etc. */  
  while (! displayConnectionDetails()) {
    delay(1000);
  }

   server.begin();

}

void loop()
{

  Adafruit_CC3000_ClientRef client = server.available();  

  if (client) {
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    //Serial.print("client found");

    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        // if you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
        // character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
        // so you can send a reply
        if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
          // send a standard http response header
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println();

          // output the value of each analog input pin
          for (int analogChannel = 1; analogChannel < 2; analogChannel++) {
            client.print("Sensor Reading ");
            client.print(analogChannel);
            client.print(" is ");
            client.print(analogRead(analogChannel));
            client.println("<br />");
          }
          break;
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
          // you're starting a new line
          currentLineIsBlank = true;
        } 
        else if (c != '\r') {
          // you've gotten a character on the current line
          currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);
    // close the connection:
    client.close();
  }
}


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Displays the driver mode (tiny of normal), and the buffer
            size if tiny mode is not being used

    @note   The buffer size and driver mode are defined in cc3000_common.h
*/
/**************************************************************************/
void displayDriverMode(void)
{
  #ifdef CC3000_TINY_DRIVER
    Serial.println(F("CC3000 is configure in 'Tiny' mode"));
  #else
    Serial.print(F("RX Buffer : "));
    Serial.print(CC3000_RX_BUFFER_SIZE);
    Serial.println(F(" bytes"));
    Serial.print(F("TX Buffer : "));
    Serial.print(CC3000_TX_BUFFER_SIZE);
    Serial.println(F(" bytes"));
  #endif
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Tries to read the CC3000's internal firmware patch ID
*/
/**************************************************************************/
uint16_t checkFirmwareVersion(void)
{
  uint8_t major, minor;
  uint16_t version;

#ifndef CC3000_TINY_DRIVER  
  if(!cc3000.getFirmwareVersion(&major, &minor))
  {
    Serial.println(F("Unable to retrieve the firmware version!\r\n"));
    version = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print(F("Firmware V. : "));
    Serial.print(major); Serial.print(F(".")); Serial.println(minor);
    version = major; version <<= 8; version |= minor;
  }
#endif
  return version;
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Tries to read the 6-byte MAC address of the CC3000 module
*/
/**************************************************************************/
void displayMACAddress(void)
{
  uint8_t macAddress[6];

  if(!cc3000.getMacAddress(macAddress))
  {
    Serial.println(F("Unable to retrieve MAC Address!\r\n"));
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print(F("MAC Address : "));
    cc3000.printHex((byte*)&macAddress, 6);
  }
}


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Tries to read the IP address and other connection details
*/
/**************************************************************************/
bool displayConnectionDetails(void)
{
  uint32_t ipAddress, netmask, gateway, dhcpserv, dnsserv;

  if(!cc3000.getIPAddress(&ipAddress, &netmask, &gateway, &dhcpserv, &dnsserv))
  {
    Serial.println(F("Unable to retrieve the IP Address!\r\n"));
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print(F("\nIP Addr: ")); cc3000.printIPdotsRev(ipAddress);
    Serial.print(F("\nNetmask: ")); cc3000.printIPdotsRev(netmask);
    Serial.print(F("\nGateway: ")); cc3000.printIPdotsRev(gateway);
    Serial.print(F("\nDHCPsrv: ")); cc3000.printIPdotsRev(dhcpserv);
    Serial.print(F("\nDNSserv: ")); cc3000.printIPdotsRev(dnsserv);
    Serial.println();
    return true;
  }
}
```

[HELP]
at this line

```
      // output the value of each analog input pin
      for (int analogChannel = 1; analogChannel < 2; analogChannel++) {
        client.print("Sensor Reading ");
        client.print(analogChannel);
        client.print(" is ");
        client.print(analogRead(analogChannel));
        client.println("<br />");
```

the values shown are in whole numbers. how can i change it to have decimal numbers?
tried using float at

```
            client.print(float analogRead(analogChannel));
```

but it just gives me error. any workaround? to have a decimal point at the output?

Answer (score 1):

analogRead returns an int. That is why you are seeing whole numbers, between 0 and 1023. What were you hoping for? If, for instance, you were using a reference voltage of 3v, you could do:

```
float v = 3.0*((float)analogRead(channel))/1024.0;
client.print(v);
```